# Prove that there exists a subspace W' and a function $T:V \to V$ such that T is a projection on W along W'

Tags: linear-algebra

Prove that there exists a subspace W' and a function $T:V \to V$ such that T is a projection on W along W'

A fucntion T : V $\to$ V is a projection on $W_1$ along $W_2$ if for $x=x_1+x_2$ with $x_i \in$ $W_i$, i=1,2. we have $T(x)=x_1$

How do i go about this?

Thanks

Comment: What is $W$? What did you try?

Answer (score 1):

It follows simply by definition that for any vector $x_2\in W_2$ we have $T(x_2)=0$ (since $T(x_1+x_2)=T(x_1)+T(x_2)=x_1=x_1+0$ and $T(x_1)=x_1$).

and so we have a transformation such that $dim(img(T))=dim(W_1)$ and $dim(ker(T))=dim(W_2)$

that should give you enough to start thinking about the problem